# How to add more shortcuts to android studio toolbar?

Tags: android, android-studio

**I just want to add few more shortcuts to the android studio toolbar like eclipse :**

http://imageshack.com/a/img571/2480/ehn0.png

**This is the image link:** http://imageshack.com/a/img571/2480/ehn0.png

After I go to the settings for android studio, I see a option for menus and toolbars. I am just not sure how to add items to my toolbar from this point.

[Some Image http://imageshack.com/a/img841/521/bz0a.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img841/521/bz0a.jpg)

These are the shortcuts I want to add:

**1) To Create new class**

**2) New Android Layout**

**3) New Package**

If possible, I also want to add some code stuff like :

**1) Generate Getters and Setters**

**2) Override Methods**

**3) Add Unimplemented methods**

**4) Surround With**

If anyone knows how to do it, it will be a great help for me and hopefully others too.

Comment: the fastest way to learn how to do it - ask about it in intellij support.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Right-click on the **open space** of the toolbar (your first image) and select `Customize Menus and Toolbars...`.

Now open the `Main Toolbar` folder, select any item and then click the `Add After...` button (on the right).

Find what you want to add from the list of items available (you can also choose an icon) and click `OK`.

The new item is added :)

You can also re-arrange the items by selecting it and using the `Move Up` and `Move Down` buttons.

Click `OK` when done.

**NOTE:**
You can also do this from the settings (as per your second image) but it is faster to do by right-clicking the toolbar.

Comment: That's awesome !! thanks..this is what i wanted .. :D ..makes the work so fast and east ..:D

Comment: Thanks! What a stupid name for an action: "Add After..."

Comment: This doesn't work for me on AS 3.6.3. I can follow all the steps you mentioned up to adding a button, but it doesn't actually get added! Even after an app restart, the configuration dialog shows that my button should be there, but it isn't! What gives?! Same goes for if I try to *remove* one of the buttons included by default...weird!

Answer (score 9):

I'm currently using Android Studio 3.6.1.
Maybe you currently have toolbar unchecked, like I had.
So first go to View -> Appearance and check Toolbar option.

[image: select_appearance_under_the_view]

After that, you'll be able to right click on a toolbar and you'll get option to choose:

[image: customize_menus_and_toolbars]

Choose option *Customize menus and toolbars*.
You'll get the following dialog:

[image: menus_and_toolbars]

Choose main toolbar:

[image: main_toolbar_chosen]

Here, under main toolbar, you see all of the actions that are currently available on your screen.
Now, choose the place where you want to add your action, and then click on +.
[image: add_action_or_separator]

You can now search for the action you want to add. For example, I have searched for *Open Dart DevTools* action.

[image]

After you click on OK, the action will appear in your main toolbar.
[image]

That's it. Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what version of Android Studio the accepted answer above covers but it left out an essential step as of Android Studio 3.3.1,  Step #1 as noted below.

- Step #1:  Confirm your Toolbar is actually visible in Android Studio.
  Select Menu -> View -> Toolbar to toggle the toolbar's visibility to
  visible.
- Step #2:  Right Click in a blank area of the toolbar to reveal popup
  menu "Customize Menus and Toolbars".  Choose "Customize Menus and
  Toolbars".
- Step #3:  Expand Main Toolbar in popup window.
- Step #4:  Choose toolbar item where you desire to add an item after
  it.
- Step #5:  For a separator choose "Add Separator".  For a toolbar
  button choose "Add After".
- Step #6:  Assuming you chose "Add After" in Step #5 find the
  button/action you desire to be added in the popup window provided. 
  Choose that item.
- Step #7:  Choose okay to add item to previous popup window.  New
  button/icon/action item should now appear in the current popup
  window.
- Step #8:  Choose okay to finish the toolbar edit desired.
- Step #9:  Repeat as necessary/desired from Step #2.

Comment: There is no "Add after" button in Android Studio 3.5.1, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the icon after which you want to add new set of icons.
2. Then Add a separator to create new group.
3. Add the icon by selecting the new separator created in step to and click on "Add After.." button. which displays a popup from which you can search for the icons you need.
4. Repeat step-3 to add more icons.

Answer (score 0):

You get the same toolbar editor menu by going to
>Preferences >Appearance & behaviour >Menus & toolbars

Depending on **which** menu you need to edit expand one of:

- Separate topmost toolbar(*has right-click edit context menu*): **Main toolbar**
- Toolbar combined with the editor's navigation bar(*has no edit context menu*): **Navigation bar toolbar**

[image: settings]